# Is the contrapositive to the following statement of an exercise in hungerford correct?

Tags: propositional-calculus

Background:

**Exercise 5:**  If $a=bc$ with $a\neq 0$ and $b$ and $c$ nonunits, show that $a$ is not an associate of $b$

**Questions:**

For the above question, is the contrapositive of the statement of the above exercise: if $a$ is an associate of $b$, and $a=bc$ with $a\neq 0$ then $b$ or $c$ is a unit.

I am haveing trouble with the latter part of the statement which has the following:

$a=bc$

$a\neq 0$

$b$ is a not a unit

$c$ is a not a unit

$b$ is a not a unit, $c$ is a not a unit, I can negate it to become a disjunction.  But "$a=bc$ with $a\neq 0$", do I treat the "with" here as an  *and*, or do i simply consider "$a=bc$ with $a\neq 0$" as one single statement?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Some major mathjax is missing -- your proposed converse is unreadable

Comment: @coffeemath I fixed it. I was missing a dollar sign.

Comment: I think you need to replace the tail end "and either b
 or c
 are units." by  "then either b or c is a unit.

Comment: @coffeemath do you mean like this:  "For the above question, is the contrapositive of the statement of the above exercise that $a$ is an associate of $b$ then if $a=bc$ with $a\neq 0$ then either $b$ or $c$ is a unit."

Comment: Be careful how you use the word "if." You started with a statement in the form "if P then Q" and you seem to be trying to write "not Q then if not P." That's not a contrapositive; it's not even a grammatical sentence. You should be writing "if not Q then not P."

Comment: @DavidK I edited the statement of the contrapositive, I think the portion "$a=bc$ with $a\neq 0$, I am not sure if that is treated as a separate statement or do I treat it as part of $b$ and $c$ are nonunits.

Comment: I think you have a true statement now that's derivable from the contrapositive, but not the same thing. You seem to be making this exercise more complicated than it ought to be. Identify P and Q in the original statement so that the statement is "if P then Q"; then write "if not Q then not P". The only additional rewriting of the sentence should be to phrase "not Q" and "not P" in a more natural way, but not to shuffle little bits of P or Q from the "if" part to the "then" part or vice versa.

Comment: @DavidK I edit my post to reflect why I was having trouble with writing out the contrapositive.  There is a grammartical issue of dealing with the word "with".  I am not sure how to symbolize that in therms of symboblic logic.

Comment: That clarifies the question immensely, thanks. I agree with the answer that was posted yesterday; in this case, "with" is a stylish way of saying "and".

Comment: Stop using MathJax to format text, please. Use markdown. This is very far from the first time you've been told this.

Answer (score 2):

Given:

((= with ≠0) and ( and  nonunits)) $\rightarrow$ ( is not an associate of ).

The contrapositive is:

$\neg$ ( is not an associate of ) $\rightarrow$ $\neg$ ((= with ≠0) and ( and  nonunits)).

$\neg$ ( is not an associate of ) $\rightarrow \neg$ ((= $\land$ ≠0) $\land$ ( nonunit $\land$  nonunit))

( is an associate of ) $\rightarrow$ ($\neg$(= $\land$ ≠0) $\lor$ $\neg$( nonunit $\land$  nonunit))

( is an associate of ) $\rightarrow$ $\neg$(=) $\lor$ $\neg$(≠0) $\lor$ ( unit $\lor$  unit)

( is an associate of ) $\rightarrow$ ($\neq$) $\lor$ (=0) $\lor$ ( unit $\lor$  unit)

( is an associate of ) $\rightarrow$ ($\neq$) $\lor$ (=0) $\lor$ ( unit) $\lor$ ( unit)

I would write: If   is an associate of  then $a\neq bc$ or $a=0$ or $b$ is a unit or $c$ is a unit.

I don't know the actual content of your statement so it may make sense to stop applying the negations earlier to have your contrapositive statement that you would like to prove. The statement as you wrote it is missing some if/then structure.

Comment: if $a$ is an associate of $b$ then $a=bc$ with $b$ is a unit or $c$ is a unit?  I mean it doesn't contradict the part where you state "$a\neq bc$ or $a=0$ or $b$ is a unit or $c$ is a unit."

Comment: I'm confused by you saying with. The statement evaluates as true if, provided that $a$ is an associate of $b$, that you can prove that one of the 4 statements separated by ORs after the arrow hold. I'll edit to make the 4 possibilities clearer since I kept the last two together.

Comment: usually with "$b$ is an associate of $a$ means that $a=bc$ for some unit $c.$  I am just wondering if $b$ or $c$ is a unit, that would mean that $a=bc$

Comment: If, when considering the contrapositive, you can prove that c is a unit, then you satisfy the OR after the arrow, and the statement is true. Since it is true, its contrapositive, which is your original statement, is also true. You only discover things about $a=bc$ in the contrapositive direction, and in the original direction, you assume it is so.

Comment: ah so in the contrapositive if I assume that $a$ is an associate of $b$ and show that $c$ is a unit, then I have proved the contrapositive statement.  And hence taking the contrapositivev again, gives $a-bc$.  That is what you maen?

Comment: First sentence: yes you satisfy the statement, making both the contrapositive and the original true, with all their implications. Since I don't know the topic you're studying, I'm not able to say much about what you can traditionally assume or would be driving at with your proof. I was trying to illustrate the creation of the contrapositive and passing the negation through various AND and OR statements so you see how it's done. I immediately edited my prior comment when I realized I had misread the sentence, and your second sentence is probably off: in the original statement, we assume $a=bc$.

Comment: Okay thank you.

Comment: I edited my question. I was wondering if i can ask you something quick.  When i see a statement in propositional calculus or in a math statement, how do I intepret the word "with".  Do i consider that as an "and"?

Comment: I view it as an “and”.

Comment: ah kk.  thank you.  It is these little grammar points that trips me up.