# Quick question about notation in proof of a proposition in group theory.

Tags: group-theory, notation, proof-explanation

*Background:*

**Proposition 1:**  Let $L$ be a group and $G$ and $H$ be two subgroups.  Then, the following statements are equivalent:

1. $L,G$ and $H$ satisfy the following relations:  $L=GH, G\cap H=\{1\},$ and $|G,H|=\{1\}.$
2. $L$ is the direct product of $G$ and $H,$ i.e. $L\cong G\times H.$

> Proof:  Write
>
> $$G=\{(g,1),g\in G\}$$
>
> and
>
> $$H=\{(1,h),h\in H\}$$
>
> Then, obviously $L=GH$ and $G\cap H=\{1\}.$  For $[G,H]=\{1\},$ we have
>
> $$(g,1)(1,h)(g,1)^{-1}(1,h)^{-1}=(1,1).$$

*Questions:*

I just have a quick question about:  $(g,1)(1,h)(g,1)^{-1}(1,h)^{-1}=(1,1).$, specifically in $(g,1)^{-1}(1,h)^{-1}$, does $(g,1)^{-1}=(1,g^{-1})$ and similarly $(1,h)^{-1}=(h^{-1}, 1)$?

Thank you in advance

Comment: No, in a direct product $A\times B$, $(x,y)^{-1}$ is $(x^{-1},y^{-1})$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson ah kk.  thank you.

Comment: **Stop** using mathjax to format text. Why do we need to tell you this hundreds of times, and why do you stubbornly insist on doing it?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I thought I am using Latex code, and the corrections you made are html markup code

Comment: You are using mathjax in order to use **bad** LaTeX code (in LaTeX you do **not** use math mode for text formatting *either*). I've explained this to you **multiple** times: you should **not** use mathjax for text formatting, you should use mark up. I have also explained to you **why**. But clearly, you are not listening. Why that is, I don't know. But I am not going to explain it to you yet again. I'm just going to call you out and downvote you until you stop misusing mathjax.

Comment: And I am not [the only one who has told you this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4857028/is-the-contrapositive-to-the-following-statement-of-an-exercise-in-hungerford-co). I told you about forcing black color [a month ago](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4866069/clarification-needed-for-an-exercise-concerning-inverse-limit-in-basic-group-the). And about sizing problems you cause. And you are not even doing *good* $\LaTeX$. You are doing *terrible* $\LaTeX$ with the mathjax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(g,h)\in G\times H$. Consider $(g^{-1}, h^{-1})$. We have

$$\begin{align}
(g,h)(g^{-1}, h^{-1})&=(gg^{-1}, hh^{-1})\\
&=(e_G, e_H)=e_{G\times H}\\
&=(g^{-1}g,h^{-1}h)\\
&=(g^{-1}, h^{-1})(g,h).\\
\end{align}$$

Therefore, by uniqueness of inverses, we have $(g,h)^{-1}=(g^{-1}, h^{-1}).$

Comment: thank you.  I hope you are keeping well.

Comment: You're welcome, @Seth. Please don't forget to upvote and accept this answer if it is satisfactory.